# Benchmarking some Javascript Frameworks

Tags: javascript, frameworks, firebug, benchmarking, performance-testing

So first of all, I'm going to be benchmarking some functions in different javascript frameworks. And I was wondering what kind of programs I can use to monitor resources like MEM% usage, CPU% usage, DOM count, time it takes to render/display/close functions. So far I have been using firebug and performance monitor and pushtotest. I have found these programs useful, some have downsides, so I'm caught scrambling in between these. I'm wondering if theres a more efficient method/program to use.
Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

It depends in the environment you are using. For Windows you would probably use perfmon and on Unix/ Linux you can use sar. Please state some details so we can provide more specific advice.
Mark.

Comment: What the hell is sar and perfmon(I found know this one). Could you not provide links? I guess found the links myself. Sar => http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar, perfmon => http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx

Comment: @Alfred, sar is the system activity reporter